# Create broadcastable TX offline on Windows

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction, offline

I made a tool which created 500 transactions that I need to have broadcasted on the network.

The data, nonce and other information is all available. The only thing I need is a way to create the transaction and sign it with my private key.

What would be the easiest way that won't give me a headache? I don't think you even need a copy of the chain for this as its just signing. (I do not need it broadcasted to the network right now)

Please no Web3 or anything else with NodeJS, because every single time I use javascript/NodeJS it takes me hours to fight through the errors NPM shoots at me. I'm probably hospitalized because of high blood pressure before the libraries even finished installing so please think of my health

Anyways I've been searching for quite a while so if someone could save me out of the fire, I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `web3` inside `geth` is okay with you, first import the private key into `geth` via `geth account import`, and then just run this in the `geth` console (replacing the addresses, nonce, and value):

```
web3.personal.unlockAccount('0x123abc...')
web3.eth.signTransaction({ from: '0x123abc...', to: '0xdef789...', value: '1234567000000000000', gas: 21000, gasPrice: '1000000000', nonce: 1, chainId: 1 })
```

As an alternative, MyEtherWallet supports creating offline transactions, too. The website can be downloaded and executed completely offline.

Comment: I'll give this a try, sounds good. I'll let you know

Comment: Worked as expected! I'm now integrating the HTTP RPC of geth in my code to automatically sign the transactions and store them for later broadcasting! Thanks!